# collectionViewContentSize() vs contentSize

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

What is the difference between

`collectionViewController.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize()` and `collectionViewController.collectionView.contentSize` ?

What do you prefer to use?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`collectionViewContentSize()` is a method you can override (in the layout) to generate the size dynamically.

`contentSize` is a property of `collectionView` (or any `UIScrollView`, for that matter) that is going to be used if there is no such override.

It is similar to a `UITableView`'s `rowHeight` vs. the `UITableViewDelegate`'s `heightForRowAtIndexPath()`.

Please also note (as mentioned in the comments) that "`contentSize` is a `UIScrollView`-inherited property, while `itemSize` is the property on `UICollectionViewLayout` that allows you to specify a blanket size for each cell".

Comment: `contentSize` in collectionView is inherited from UIScrollView, and so API says it is 'The size of the content view'. That means that it should be the total, the whole content of each cell. And not just the uniform `contentSize` of the particular cells, what you analogy would indicate. Am I right?

Comment: You're confusing contentSize with itemSize.  contentSize is a UIScrollView-inherited property, while itemSize is the property on UICollectionViewLayout that allows you to specify a blanket size for each cell.

Comment: `collectionViewContentSize` must be inherited by all subclasses of `UICollectionViewLayout` and should not be phrased as "you can override".

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize

Answer (score 6):

`contentSize` is a property of `UIScrollView`, whereas `collectionViewContentSize()` is a method of `UICollectionViewLayout`.

Reading [Programming iOS 7, 4th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920031017.do), whilst summarising `UICollectionViewLayout`, the author states:

> The layout workhorse class for a collection view. A collection view
>   cannot exist without a layout instance! As I’ve already said, the
>   layout knows how much room all the subviews occupy, and ***supplies the
>   collectionViewContentSize that sets the contentSize of the collection
>   view, qua scroll view.***

From personal experience I encountered difficulties using `layout.collectionViewContentSize()`. Either the console showed the warning below, or the layouts appeared initially incorrect.

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.
```

My guess is that `collectionViewContentSize()` does more than just return the content size. I think that invoking this actually initiates the layout calculations. If - *during those calculations* - anomalies are detected, then the warning shown is output.

For me testing on iPad and initiating the collection view via a Xib, the Xib's frames were iPhone sized. Initial passes triggered from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` were dealing with the small view. Checking the collection view's frame, it *was* too small. Subsequent layout engine passes eventually delivered the correct sizes, but by then the warnings had already been displayed.

Next, I tried making the Xib frame much larger. This obviated the error, but caused a worse problem; layouts were initially wrong. In scrolling, you would see the items jump around as the layout was recalculated to the correct dimensions.

Possibly the answer is to call `invalidateLayout()`, but I'm not sure where. I tried after instantiating the collection view and that didn't work.

So, the answer? I used ***contentSize***. Initial passes in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` still show incorrect sizes but eventually come good. It doesn't generate any console warnings and better still, doesn't trigger any erroneous layout based upon the old frame size. Even better, rotation is handled automatically as `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called automatically by which point the content size will have been updated.