# UICollectionViewFlowLayout: collectionView!.contentSize vs collectionViewContentSize

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uikit-dynamics

#### Update

The issue seems to be resolved when using the designated `collectionViewContentSize()` method like so:

```
let contentSize = collectionViewContentSize()
```

Nevertheless, I would be very interested in an explanation behind this behaviour, so I've updated my question accordingly.

#### Original Question

I am trying to recreate the steps found in the first example of [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html), but using Swift and Storyboards.

I have a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass with the following content:
import UIKit

```
class SpringyFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    private lazy var animator: UIDynamicAnimator = {
        return UIDynamicAnimator(collectionViewLayout: self)
        }()
    
    override func prepareLayout() {
        super.prepareLayout()
        
        let contentSize = collectionView!.contentSize
        let items = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: contentSize)) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
        
        if animator.behaviors.isEmpty {
            for item in items {
                let spring = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: item, attachedToAnchor: item.center)
                spring.length = 0
                spring.damping = 0.8
                spring.frequency = 1.0
                animator.addBehavior(spring)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
        return animator.itemsInRect(rect)
    }
    
    
    override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
        return animator.layoutAttributesForCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
    
    override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        let delta = newBounds.origin.y - collectionView!.bounds.origin.y
        for spring in animator.behaviors {
            let items = spring.items as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
            if let attributes = items.first {
                attributes.center.y += delta
                animator.updateItemUsingCurrentState(attributes)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

I have the correct Layout class set in Storyboards. When I run the app, my Collection View is empty.

I have determined that the issue is in the following snipped:

```
override func prepareLayout() {
        super.prepareLayout()
        
        let contentSize = collectionView!.contentSize
        let items = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: contentSize)) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
//...
}
```

Since I subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, I thought I can rely on the super implementation to lay out the elements for me, and then modify their attributes. But when I check contentSize, it reports the width correctly, but the height is 0.

This leads to an empty items array -> no behaviors in `animator` -> `animator.itemsInRect(_)` returning an empty array -> the empty Collection View.

I just can't seem to find out what I'm missing. There should be no need to override the  `contentSize()` method, since I'm using a flow layout.

Answer (score 3):

The issue it that collectionView doesn't yet have a content size, because it just started to prepare it's layout. I don't believe that calling `collectionView!.contentSize` will actually compute the size. The reason `collectionViewContentSize()` works is because it will compute the size using your other layout code.

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, calling super's implementation of `prepareLayout()` should have taken care of laying out the collection view (as it is a simple flow layout), so my collectionView should be already aware of its content size (`collectionView!.contentSize` is indeed only returning this value). That's why this situation is so confusing.

Comment: I don't think so. It looks like `prepareLayout()` doesn't do the whole layout. It just does any prep before the more hefty methods are called.

Comment: If you don't override the `collectionViewContentSize()` method, the default implementation will query the `contentSize` property of your collection view (inherited from `UIScrollView`. So I feel like I'm also using this property under the hood, but for some reason it's incorrect on the first attempt..

Comment: Where do you find that `collectionViewContentSize()` uses `collectionView.contentSize`?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333294/collectionviewlayout-collectionviewcontentsize-vs-collectionviecontroller-coll)

Comment: Not correct. contentSize uses collectionViewContentSize(), not vice versa. See "supplies the collectionViewContentSize that sets the contentSize of the collection". See Programming iOS 7 Fourth Edition

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you might find interesting.  I noticed in Ash Furrow's [example](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html) in viewDidAppear a call to collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout.  Ash notes this isn't necessary when using storyboards due a difference in timing of the first invocation of prepareLayout versus when storyboards are not used.

I tried invalidating the collection view layout in viewDidAppear along with your code and a storyboard.  Here is what I found:

Test Scenarios:

1) collectionView!.contentSize without invalidateLayout = cv is EMPTY

2) collectionViewContentSize() without invalidateLayout = cv WORKS

3) collectionView!.contentSize with invalidateLayout = cv WORKS

4) collectionViewContentSize() with invalidateLayout = cv WORKS

FYI